# eth.getCode is returning "0x" at contract's address

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, gas

On deploying a contract using Remix on private net and using `eth.getCode(<contract's address>)`, I am getting `"0x"` as output. A simple contract like below is giving me the same result as well:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() constant returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

I tried increasing gas limit using --targetgaslimit while initiating geth as well, but it didn't help either. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Adding output of Tx Receipt:

```
>eth.getTransactionReceipt("0xb0e9618bc1b05b59fc4624ae7c4db9f95f22bfd24982ef55c5f28ce7e626977c")
{
  blockHash: "0xae9bad233840e5acc872f167b3084e037c64d60d93c0229cdd6e9bc8229169d5",
  blockNumber: 26245,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 22872,
  from: "0x59d974cd767e994176c4950b7a231cb7c5403ec5",
  gasUsed: 22872,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0xff06b18b48d1c2822d15cd03af57fd29ec67b69c6051587477858dbe3e4398da",
  to: "0x8584fa5f7c42783647c0fe344abf31b04886bc12",
  transactionHash: "0xb0e9618bc1b05b59fc4624ae7c4db9f95f22bfd24982ef55c5f28ce7e626977c",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Comment: has the contract transaction been mined?

Comment: Yes, it is getting mined as I am able to see valid block# in the TransactionReceipt

Comment: contractAddress is null so you will not get a return. Make sure the address parameter is in hex!

Comment: Updating my geth client to v1.7.2 resolved the issue somehow!

Answer (score 2):

I think your forgot to add an 0x to your contract address when calling that function.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API
web3.eth.getCode

web3.eth.getCode(addressHexString [, defaultBlock] [, callback])
Get the code at a specific address.

Parameters

String - The address to get the code from.
Number|String - (optional) If you pass this parameter it will not use the default block set with web3.eth.defaultBlock.
Function - (optional) If you pass a callback the HTTP request is made asynchronous. See this note for details.
Returns

String - The data at given address addressHexString.

Comment: I am picking up contract's address from following logs generated during mining: `INFO [11-16|14:34:19] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0xb0e9618bc1b05b59fc4624ae7c4db9f95f22bfd24982ef55c5f28ce7e626977c recipient=0x8584fa5f7c42783647c0fe344abf31b04886bc12` and querying `eth.getCode("0x8584fa5f7c42783647c0fe344abf31b04886bc12")` which is returning me "0x"